# Angular2: What type of validation should be done through custom validators?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, submit

I am working on a projected with typescript and Angular 2 and don't know how to continue on my application. I currently have a page with several radio buttons and have applied model-based forms to my page, and have successfully made all radio buttons mandatory with the `<any>Validators.required` functionality. I am able to display an error message if any set of radio buttons have no been selected yet

The next thing I need to do is to check that the correct radio buttons have been 'checked' throughout the page. Is this something I should do through validation? Solving this problem could be done in the "onSubmit" function that I call, but I would rather be able to display error messages on the fly, when they user is marking off the radio buttons to let them know they chose poorly.

Any help on this topic is greatly appreciated. I don't see any reason to upload any code snippets, but if you think you need it I can very quickly get something up.